# IE11 Can't Tell that Two Strings are Equal

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

For whatever reason, a condition is returning `false` when by all my accounts, it should be true.  It's just a simple string comparison; **and Chrome gets it right**.

In the IE developer tools, I put a breakpoint on the line, and tried different things.  Here's the output:
[image]

The code this is getting called from is a jQueryUI widget.  Here's the full block that the code is running in.  I can post the entire widget if that's helpful.

```
this.element.children('option').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === select.val()) {  // Why does this evaluate to false?!?!?
        $(this).text(value)
        ctl._trigger('select', event, {
            item: this
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: That's really weird. What if you wrote a loop to compare them character by character? Not as a solution to the problem, but just to see if it would fail at a specific character or what.

Comment: Also what's the output of `$(this).text() == "Matched Base Revenue"` and `select.val() == "Matched Base Revenue"`

Comment: Perhaps if you try `.trim()` function for each string. I've once come across this in IE8 (it added an extra space in the end for no apparent reason). So `$(this).text().trim() === select.val().trim()` . You could also try `.toString()` for the string. Just in case.

Comment: Also, have you replicated this on another machine? This is weird enough that it could be anything.

Comment: Use `==` instead of `===` when comparing them.

Comment: @MelanciaUK The final test in the console screenshot does that - still `false`

Comment: @JamesThorpe I've missed that bit.

Comment: Does `$(this).text.match(/[\w ]+/)[0]` and `select.val().match(/[\w ]+/)[0]` return the same thing? I believe some of you space-like characters aren't spaces. Also, do you only experience this issue in the console?

Comment: Curiously, it works for me. Tested on Chrome, Firefox and IE 11: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/cm8totf9/

Comment: Try: `$(this).text().valueOf() === select.val().valueOf()`

Comment: @MelanciaUK `valueOf()` still shows false.

Comment: That's pretty weird! Try my `jsFiddle` in your IE 11 and tell me the result.

Comment: @plalx, the regular expression shows: "Matched Base" for one, and "Matched Base Revenue" for the other.  That white space character is 32 for one, and 160 for the other!  Write up an answer and I'll mark it correct.  Thanks!

Comment: Was this happening only in `IE`?

Comment: Yes, Chrome was working fine (didn't test any other browsers).  I did change the IE compatibility mode to 10 and 9, and I got the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Does `$(this).text.match(/[\w ]+/)[0]` and `select.val().match(/[\w ]+/)[0]` return the same thing?

I believe some of you space-like characters aren't spaces.

Comment: To solve the problem in my comparison, I followed the solution found here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646964/javascript-jquery-removing-character-160-from-a-nodes-text-value-regex